# CMake finds boost libraries but Make fails to link them

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, cmake

After coming back to a project after a month I am able to run CMake successfully with the following output

```
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/LittleNewt/gitness/MangaMeCLI/build
```

but for some reason when running Make on the generated MakeFile I get the following output

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mangaMeCLI.dir/src/mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable mangaMeCLI
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
      boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::current_path() in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&) in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&) in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
      boost::filesystem::is_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&) in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.75 in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.73 in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.74 in mangaMeCLI.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [mangaMeCLI] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mangaMeCLI.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did some research and have found others having the same issues due to not linking the correct version of the libraries for there architecture (64bit vs 32bit) but am not sure how to identify if this is the issue for me.

Here is my unchanged CMakeLists.txt file

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.4.1)
PROJECT(MangaMeCLI)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(includes)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(mangaMeCLI src/mangaMeCLI.cpp)
MESSAGE("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread filesystem)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mangaMeCLI ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})

SET(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/*)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mangaMeCLI ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})

FIND_PACKAGE(cppnetlib REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CPPNETLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mangaMeCLI ${CPPNETLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

After reading a useful comment I found that the BOOST_LIBRARIES variable was empty even though cmake prints that it found the boost libraries I was looking for. I am assuming this is the reason for my error.

Comment: `...(64bit vs 32bit) but am not sure how to identify if this is the issue for me.` - Libraries which CMake has found are stored in `BOOST_LIBRARIES` variable. You may add line `message(${BOOST_LIBRARIES})` for output value of this variable (during `cmake` phase), and inspect libraries.

Comment: Additionally, you can try to `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` before invoking `find_package(Boost...)` to enable debug output from FindBoost.

Comment: After turning on debug I found this NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH multiple times, thanks for the help I will look into this and see if this is the reason for my error
edit: after looking into this it seems to be ok as I did no specify a root path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake variables are case-sensitive. As per the [find module's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), you want `Boost_LIBRARIES`, not `BOOST_LIBRARIES`:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mangaMeCLI ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: that worked, must have been a change in one of the newer cmake version as the capital BOOST used to work fine, would you recommend I change my other find_packages to match the spelling of the package name, such as OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS?

Comment: @Jem4687 Yes, CMake is moving towards unifying the find-produced variable names to use the exact case of the find module name. Of course, if you can and if the module supports them, it's even better to use imported targets with usage requirements (then you don't have to care about include directories and such). Boost, does support them, according to the docs I linked.